# Deploy angular app in server

Tags: angular

Develop a small application with Angular. When doing the `ng build --prod`, I pass to my server the `/dist` folder generated with the `--base-href /test/` (the `/test/` folder is where I have my application) and everything works very well running in the browser `www-mysite.com /test`, BUT if I update the browser, the application stops working.

Comment: What do you mean by "update the browser"?

Comment: I mean refresh the webside

Comment: set a default router

Comment: @Shohel how set?

Comment: I have added a link in my answer which will help you set them. what type of server you are using ?

Comment: is server linux with centos

Comment: Then you should be able to figure it out from the link i gave. Accept the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you will have to use some kind of redirect_mode (depending on your server) to `redirect all requests to index.html`. This is needed for all single page applications.

If you will refresh on www.mysite.com, it will work. It will break when you refresh on /test route. This is because your routes are defined on client side and server is unaware of them.

Read more about how to configure this here: https://medium.com/@pshrmn/single-page-applications-and-the-server-32a23d67936

Comment: Thanks for your help and excuse the little knowledge: D

Comment: glad to help you